# Mantaflow doesn't interact properly with Effector (Ship) when using Copy Location

Tags: constraints, ocean-simulation, mantaflow

I have a ship that sails on the water. So that the ship floats correctly on the water, I tied it to a plane using a copy location, which takes the water movements with it using a shrink wrap.

Now I would like to use the Mantaflow to imitate a side wave that goes over the front part of the ship. If I don't use Copy Location, then the water spreads correctly on the ship, but as soon as I turn on Copy Location, the water jumps away in all directions as soon as it touches the ship, although the movements of the ship are very light with it. Does any of you know why this is or what you could do about it? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need more resolution devision when using copy location as without using it. As soon as I increased this, it worked now.